# How to correctly hide app icon from Launchpad via Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, launchpad

I have Launchpad with database just reset and I want to remove from it the iBooks icon.

Getting database path using...

```
echo $(find /private/var/folders -user $(id -u) -name com.apple.dock.launchpad 2> /dev/null)/db/db
```

Trying to remove the iBooks icon...

```
sqlite3 {PATH} "DELETE FROM apps WHERE title='iBooks';"
killall Dock
```

Now the iBooks icon really removed and everything looks good. But if I restart Launchpad again or reboot the Mac, all icons in Launchpad are mixed. How I can to fix it?