# How to remove an icon from Launchpad without removing it from Applications?

Tags: icon, launchpad

I have an older app with icon in Launchpad and now the updated app has a new icon also in the Launchpad.

I want to remove the old icon from Launchpad, so I don't click it by mistake. But I still want to be able to run the old version if needed to check on archived data files, so I want to keep the app in the Applications folder.

It was **not** downloaded from the Mac App Store so it does **not** show an the cross button when wiggling.

I am using a MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: This was answered https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144756/how-to-remove-an-icon-from-launchpad-that-does-not-appear-in-the-finder

Comment: All the answers I saw on that site removes the file. This is not what OP asked.

Comment: Here's a [recipe for removing it using the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320252/how-to-correctly-hide-app-icon-from-launchpad-via-terminal), but BEWARE... it appears to have "side-effects"